# MySQL order group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

Sorry in advance if this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find any (good) answer on this.

I think this better explains my problem

```
  CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(10)

);

INSERT INTO posts VALUES
  (1, 'Product 1'),
  (2, 'Product 2');

CREATE TABLE details(
  id INT,
  merchant VARCHAR(10),
  address INT,
  lat decimal(11,8) ,
  lng decimal(11,8) ,
  offer_group INT(10)
) ;

INSERT INTO details VALUES
  (1, 'Merchant 1',10,40.444444,60.666666,1),
  (2, 'Merchant 1',20,40.555555,60.777777,1);

SELECT  P.*, D.*  , MIN( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('40.555556') ) * cos( radians( D.lat ) ) * cos( radians( D.lng ) - radians('60.777778') ) + sin( radians('40.555556') ) * sin( radians( D.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance  FROM posts P

  JOIN details D ON D.id = P.id 

  WHERE 1=1  GROUP BY merchant ORDER BY  distance ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7db78b/6
I have separate databases but the example link shows exactly how tables are linked and my current query.

So in that example if you leave the **GROUP BY** the distance is from the merchant with address **20** but I would like to see the correct data (id = 2, name = Product 2, address = 20, lat = 40.555555 , lng = 60.777777 )

Remove the GROUP BY part to see how it looks in the first place

Thanks and sorry for bad explainations

Comment: What MySQL version do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: thanks, looked at the answer there and I tried the second approach but still have the same problem when grouping by merchant. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7db78b/27  I am not that advance in understanding these queries, I might did it wrong. Any help would be appreciated . THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 SELECT m1.* 
 FROM merchants m1 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT name, MIN(distance) AS distance FROM merchants GROUP BY name
 ) m2 ON m1.name = m2.name AND m1.distance = m2.distance
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f9676/1/0

Comment: thanks, here's a more realistic version to what I have in code, could you work with this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query,

```
SELECT m1.* 
FROM merchants m1 
WHERE m1.distance = (SELECT MIN(distance) FROM merchants m2 where m1.name = m2.name);
```